# JPA CascadeType priority?

Tags: jpa

Using JPA i have a question relating to the CascadeTypes.

for Example:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

is different to this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

Why?
I need the cascadetype persist to automatically insert referenced objects in my 
entityclass. and i need merge because i dont want to have double entries in my
tables. but when i define persist first, merging doesnt work, when i define
merge first, persist doesnt work.

why?

Comment: The order shouldn't matter. Either your provider has an issue, which it shouldn't if it is JPA compliant, or there is a problem with the entity structure you are calling persist or merge on.  Can you post what you are doing?

Comment: what JPA provider are you currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA specification is actually a very readable document and can be downloaded here:

https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html

Inside it on page 384 it covers the `cascade` attribute of the `ManyToMany` annotation:

> The cascade element specifies the set of cascadable operations that
>   are propagated to the associated entity. The operations that are
>   cascadable are defined by the CascadeType enum: public enum
>   CascadeType { ALL, PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH}; The value
>   cascade=ALL is equivalent to cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH,
>   DETACH}.

As you can see it says nothing about the order.  What is probably happening is your application is sometimes using a new object that needs to be persisted and sometimes loading one from the database that then needs to be merged.  In order words, its an application issue.

Personally I use a DIY approach to merging entities in my persistence context.  A good article to read on the subject is here:

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/23/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/